# Setting SharePoint Folder Modified Date through JSON

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to change SharepointSite>Document>Folder>ModifiedDate to current date.  I have no idea how to write JSON but looking at a few examples, I have kludged together the following. Clearly it does not work.

```
    "host": 
        "connectionName": "shared_sharepointonline",
        "operationId": "HttpRequest",
        "apiId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_sharepointonline"
   
    "parameters": 
        "dataset": "https://splm.sharepoint.com/sites/PresentationsinProgress",
        "parameters/method": "GET",
        "parameters/uri": "_api/web/documents/fields/getbyID('<Modified>')",
        "parameters/body": "fileOrFolder.setLastModified( yourDateInMilliseconds );"
    
    "authentication": "@parameters('$authentication')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ValidateUpdateListItem for this.

Try something like below.

```
{
    "formValues":[
    {
        "FieldName": "Modified",
        "FieldValue": "8/24/2022"
    }
    ],
"bNewDocumentUpdate": true
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately Power Automate fails when encountering DocumentLibraryName in the Uri field. I had set the DocumentLibraryname inital value as Documents. This is the error i get

Cannot find resource for the request ValidateUpdateListItem.
clientRequestId: c75d3e7a-1dac-4ac2-8c04-0736abcb23ff
serviceRequestId: 6e9f5ea0-c027-2000-51e9-d24c5fbe1d3f

Comment: Also make sure you update the 2 to the id of the folder you want to update in the items part of the URI. Btw, documents is often called Shared Documents out of the box. Have you tried using that displayname instead for the getbytitle?